# Branching and assembly names

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, xamarin.android

We use Visual Studio and TFS to do version/Branch control.

I'm developing a monodroid application and I want my client to have a UAT version as well as a live version. The way (As far as I know) to allow this is to have different assembly names, but this is going to cause huge issues with me whenever I merge a branch.

Is there a good way to handle this kind of merging issue?

Ta

Ross

Answer (score 0):

If you change the target package name, then that should enable you to deploy multiple copies of the same application to an Android device.

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml

Each copy of the application should have separate copies of your assemblies - although they may share the Mono runtime assemblies if you deploy debug versions.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll try that tomorrow and then mark it as the answer if it's correct (which reading the docs should be!)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work - the uat/live version just overwrite each other :(